# Django inlinemodeladmin validation - but with a generic relation

Tags: django, django-admin, models

I previously had models like this:

```
class AssemblyAnnotation(models.Model):
    assembly = models.ForeignKey(Assembly)
    type = models.ForeignKey(AssemblyAnnotationType)
    ...
    def clean(self):
        from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
        if not self.type.can_annotate_aliases and self.assembly.alias_of_id is not None:
            raise ValidationError('The selected annotation type cannot be applied to this assembly.')
```

The effect was, a new AssemblyAnnotation (attached via an inline) could only have a subset of values for it's type attribute, depending on the parent Assembly.

This worked great.

Now, it has come time to apply these annotations to other objects that are slightly different:

```
class ObjectAnnotation(models.Model):
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = generic.GenericForeignKey()
    type = models.ForeignKey(AssemblyAnnotationType)
    ...
    def clean(self):
        from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
        if self.content_type == ContentType.objects.get_for_model(Assembly):
            if not self.type.can_annotate_aliases and self.content_object.alias_of_id is not None:
                raise ValidationError('The selected annotation type cannot be applied to this assembly.')
```

As you can see, I want the same rules applied. However, there is a problem. The GenericInline that I am now using does not set self.content_type before my clean() method is run.

Is there any way around this? Am I doing this wrong?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't the right hand side return a list in
`if self.content_type == ContentType.objects.get_for_model(Assembly):`?

I would think you would need to do `if self.content_type in ContentType.objects.get_for_model(Assembly):`

Comment: No, get_for_model [returns a single ContentType object](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#django.contrib.contenttypes.models.ContentTypeManager.get_for_model). Anyway, that is not the problem. The problem is the GenericInline does not set content_type before calling clean().

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the same as you and it works as espected. Here's my code:

In the Models:

```
class GroupFlagIntermediate(models.Model):
    group_flag = models.ForeignKey(GroupFlag, related_name='flag_set')
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, verbose_name='Flag Type')
    flag_pk = models.CharField('Flag PK', max_length=100, blank=True, default='')
    flag = generic.GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'flag_pk')

    def clean(self):
        from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
        if not self.is_valid_flag(self.content_type.model_class()):
            raise ValidationError('The selected flag is not a real Flag.')
```

And in the Admin:

```
class GroupFlagIntermediateInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = GroupFlagIntermediate

class GroupFlagAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('name', ...)
    inlines = [GroupFlagIntermediateInline]

admin.site.register(GroupFlag, GroupFlagAdmin)
```

After some tests, I found that the `content_type` and `object_id` (`flag_pk` in my case) fields are set before the clean() call, but the `GenericForeignKey` (`flag` in my case) doesn't.